# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) on Iris dataset

Tags: python, flask, data-science

I'm a trying to create a machine learning model using the Iris data set (doing this by watching tutorial, complete newbie to machine learning and data science), so far I have classified it using Random Forest Classifier, but now I wish to check my predictions against custom input, my main code for classification looks like this:

```
X= iris.data
y= iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2)
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print ("Accuracy = %0.2f" % accuracy_score(y_test, rfc.predict(X_test)))
print (classification_report(y_test, rfc.predict(X_test)))
pickle.dump(rfc, open("iris_rfc1.pkl", "wb"))
my_random_forest = pickle.load(open("iris_rfc1.pkl","rb"))
url= "http://localhost:9000/api"
data = json.dumps({'sl':5.8,'sw':4,'pl':2,'pw':9})
r = requests.post(url, data)

print (r.json())
```

The Flask file I use to make connection:

```
my_random_forest = pickle.load(open('iris_rfc1.pkl','rb'))
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def make_predict():
    data = request.get_json(force = True)
    predict_request = [data['sl'],data['sw'], data['pl'], data['pw']]
    predict_request = np.array(predict_request)
    y_hat = my_random_forest.predict(predict_request)
    output = [y_hat[0]]
    return jsonify(results = output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9000, debug = True)
```

But when I run the program I get error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Additional details: I'm using Jupyter Notebook for making prediction and atom for creating the flask file, Pyhton Version 3

Answer (score 0):

The result delivered by the function make_predict() is where the error occurs.

JSON(Java Script Object Notation) can only represent/serialize a limited [group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) of data types and Numpy objects do not belong to that group.

Looking at the error message, the number 0 must be the prediction generated by the Random Forest Classifier and RFCs only operate on Numpy arrays. Their outputs too are of the same data type. The .json() method doesn't know how to serialize a numpy object.

```
>>>a = rfc.predict(np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(1,-1))
>>>a, type(a)
(array([1]), numpy.ndarray)

>>>b = a[0]
>>>b, type(b)
(1, numpy.int32)

>>>c = np.asscalar(b)
>>>c, type(c)
(1, int)
```

The y_hat is a numpy array, the first element of y_hat(output variable) is of the type np.int32. Cast it as an int using the np.asscalar() method, json() will be able to identify it.